# How to extract text from PDF file with IDENTITY-H fonts using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I have a PDF file.

I am reading Text from PDF file pro-grammatically using iTextSharp class.
It does read Ansi Encoding Texts but It does not read IDENTITY-H Encoding Texts.

My problem is how to read IDENTITY-H texts from pdf file using VB.Net

Below is my code:

1. Public Function ReadPDFFile(ByVal strSource As String) As String

   ```
   Dim sbPDFText As New StringBuilder() 'StringBuilder Object To Store read Text

   If File.Exists(strSource) Then 'Does File Exist?
       Dim pdfFileReader As New PdfReader(strSource) 'read File
       For intCurrPage As Integer = 1 To pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages 'Loop Through All Pages

           Dim lteStrategy As LocTextExtractionStrategy = New LocTextExtractionStrategy 'Read PDF File Content Blocks
           'Get Text
           Dim strCurrText As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfFileReader, intCurrPage, lteStrategy)

           sbPDFText.Append(strCurrText) 'Add Text To String Builder
       Next
       pdfFileReader.Close() 'Close File
   End If
   Return sbPDFText.ToString() 'Return
   ```

   End Function

   1. Public Overridable Sub RenderText(ByVal renderInfo As TextRenderInfo) Implements    ITextExtractionStrategy.RenderText

      ```
      Dim segment As LineSegment = renderInfo.GetBaseline()
      Dim location As New TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), segment.GetStartPoint(), segment.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth())

      If renderInfo.GetText = "" Then
          Console.WriteLine(GetResultantText())
      End If
      With location
          'Chunk Location:
          Debug.Print(renderInfo.GetText)
          .PosLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine.GetStartPoint(Vector.I1)
          .PosRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine.GetEndPoint(Vector.I1)
          .PosBottom = renderInfo.GetDescentLine.GetStartPoint(Vector.I2)
          .PosTop = renderInfo.GetAscentLine.GetEndPoint(Vector.I2)
          'Chunk Font Size: (Height)
          .curFontSize = .PosTop - segment.GetStartPoint()(Vector.I2)
          'Use Font name  and Size as Key in the SortedList
          Dim StrKey As String = renderInfo.GetFont.PostscriptFontName & .curFontSize.ToString
          'Add this font to ThisPdfDocFonts SortedList if it's not already present
          If 1 = 1 Then
              If Not ThisPdfDocFonts.ContainsKey(StrKey) Then ThisPdfDocFonts.Add(StrKey, renderInfo.GetFont)
              'Store the SortedList index in this Chunk, so we can get it later
              .FontIndex = ThisPdfDocFonts.IndexOfKey(StrKey)
              Console.WriteLine(renderInfo.GetFont.ToString & "-->" & StrKey)
          Else
              'pcbContent.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 9)
              .FontIndex = 3
              .curFontSize = 8
          End If
      End With
      locationalResult.Add(location)
      ```

      End Sub

Comment: You are mixing all kinds of concepts in a way that makes your question very confusing. The fact that a subset of the font is embedded is completely irrelevant. When the encoding is IDENTITY_H, the extracted text will be encoded using UNICODE. You are copy/pasting UNICODE characters in Notepad using a different encoding, which explains why you only see square boxes. You need to treat the extracted text as unicode text, not as WINANSI text.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for Reply. I have edited the Question. I wanted to ask to read the "IDENTITY_H" encoded Fonts.

Comment: Your question title and the body of your question don't match. The body of your question tells me that you want to extract text. The title of your question tells me that you want to extract a font. That doesn't make sense. I'll explain in a next comment why your question is invalid (some would say "stupid") and that probably also explains why it was closed.

Comment: A font program (e.g. as stored in a TTF or an OTF file) contains plenty of data about characters and glyphs. When a font is embedded in a PDF, not all data is copied into the PDF. Some data is stored in PDF objects (such as arrays with glyph widths), other data is ignored (for instance: if the letter Q doesn't appear in your document, it won't be stored in the embedded *subset*). The syntax needed to draw the glyphs used in the document is stored in a stream, but that syntax is only part of the data. It is impossible (not done, sometimes not legal) to create a font file from a PDF.

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to extract text, but you continue talking about the font (which is very confusing). The font is irrelevant when extracting text. What matters is the encoding. Which version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: I apologize for making the confusion.
I want to extract the Text which has “IDENTITY-H” Encoding.
I am using itextsharp version 5.4.5.0.

Comment: OK, when the text has IDENTITY-H encoding, then the extracted text is presented in UNICODE. You need to treat it as UNICODE. When you copy/paste it into Notepad and Notepad expects WINANSI, you'll get stuff like little squares. Please store the content in a UNICODE text file and share that file with us so that we can examine the UNICODE text file. Or better yet: share the PDF.

Comment: Please find the Link for PDF file  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxMXYx85sXDVWFhNYjhMSnNmcUk/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for sharing the PDF document. It helped us to determine that the problem you describe is **not an iTextSharp problem**. Instead it is **a problem with the PDF document itself**.

This problem doesn't have a solution, but I'm providing this answer to explain how you can discover for yourself that the problem also exists when iTextSharp isn't involved.

Open the document in Adobe Reader. Select the text "Muy señores nuestros" and copy/paste it into a text editor. You get "Muy señores nuestros". This is text that can be extracted using iTextSharp (it works correctly).

Now do the same with the text "GUARDIAN GLASS EXPRESS, S.L.". You get the following result: "". As you can see, you can not copy/paste the text correctly from Adobe Reader. This is due to the way the text is stored in the PDF. If you can not copy/paste the text from Adobe Reader, you should not expect to be able to extract the text using iTextSharp. The PDF is created in a way that doesn't allow extraction.

Please take a look at this video to find out some possible causes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE

I'm sorry that it took so long to figure this out and that it turns out that you're asking something that isn't possible. Your question narrowed the problem down too much, as if the problem was caused by the "IDENTITY-H" encoding and iTextSharp. In reality, you're trying to extract text that can't be extracted.

If you look at the page dictionary inside the PDF, you'll find three font resources for the first (and only) page:

[image]

In the content stream (below) small red arrow, you see two strings (hexadecimal notation) that are shown using fonts referenced using the names `C2_0` and `C2_1`. Incidentally, these fonts are stored as composite fonts with `/SubType` 0 and `/Encoding` Identity-H. This means that the characters used in the hexadecimal string should correspond with the UNICODE values of the glyphs. If that's not the case, you're out of luck.

There seems to be no problem with the font for which the name `/TT0` is used.

The fact that `/TT0` uses WinAnsiEncoding and the other fonts use Identity-H is **irrelevant**. There are **plenty** of PDF files with fonts that use Identity-H of which the text can be copy/pasted or extracted using iTextSharp. Unfortunately, there is probably something wrong with the way your PDF was constructed. It would take too much time to analyze what went wrong, so your best shot is to contact the person who gave you the PDF and to ask him/her to fix the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply. If you go to Document Properties --> "Fonts" Tab. it shows two different Types of Encoding. One is "Ansi" Encoding and another is "Identity-H" Encoding".So i think Text which we can copy/paste  to text editor has "Ansi" Encoding and Text which we copy/paste  into a text editor and get the following result: "", has "Identity-H" Encoding. Isn't it so?

Comment: The text "Muy señores nuestros" which we can copy/paste  into a text editor has "Ansi" Encoding and text "GUARDIAN GLASS EXPRESS, S.L." which we copy/paste  into a text editor and get the following result: "", has "Identity-H" Encoding . isn't it so?

Comment: I don't understand why you're so obsessed with one font using Ansi and the other using Identity-H. There are thousands of PDFs that use embedded fonts with Identity-H of which the text can be extracted correctly. Your PDF is an exception. Something in the way the font is used is probably wrong. It is unclear what you expect from StackOverflow readers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It means that the characters used in the hexadecimal string should correspond with the UNICODE values of the glyphs and it is not the case in the PDF file i have send to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It means that the characters used in the hexadecimal string should correspond with the UNICODE values of the glyphs and it is not the case in the PDF file i have send to you. is it so?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have a similar problem where some of the letters in my pdf is not copyable (I get weird squares). Tried exporting it to docx file using Acrobat DC, no dice either. However acrobat renders it correctly, is there a way I can export the text correctly using Acrobat?