# possible to get Pdf fonts encoding value?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

[Adobe Encoding: Build-In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34zr1.png)

I would like to get the encoding value : 'Build-in', currently i am using iTextSharp, seem like don't have any straight forward way to get the encoding value.

The only way i find to get font encoding value

```
Dim fonts As PdfDictionary = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT)
Dim fontEncoding As String = font.GetAsName(PdfName.ENCODING).ToString().Substring(1)
```

but this way unable to get some encoding value.
Such as encoding value (Build-in & Custom) `font.GetAsName(PdfName.ENCODING)` will return Nothing. For Ansi able to get value 'WinAnsiEncoding'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text from PDF file with IDENTITY-H fonts using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331421/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-file-with-identity-h-fonts-using-vb-net)

Comment: If no encoding is set (i.e. `font.GetAsName(PdfName.ENCODING)` will return `Nothing`), an encoding from within the *font program* is used.

Comment: As @mkl pointed out, `Built-in` is just an indicator that no encoding is set and encoding from the font file will be used. You can simply adjust your code to map `Nothing` into `"Built-in"` value