# MySQL database could not be updated with PHP program

Tags: php, mysql

**addmember.php**

```
  <?php
      require_once("dbtools.inc.php");
      
      $account = $_POST["account"];
      $password = $_POST["password"]; 
      $name = $_POST["name"]; 
      $sex = $_POST["sex"];
      $year = $_POST["year"]; 
      $month = $_POST["month"]; 
      $day = $_POST["day"];
      $telephone = $_POST["telephone"]; 
        
      $address = $_POST["address"];
      $email = $_POST["email"]; 
        
      $comment = $_POST["comment"];
    
      $link = create_connection();
                
    
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users Where account = '$account'";
      $result = execute_sql($link, "member", $sql);
    
    
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
      {
        mysqli_free_result($result);
            
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Account already in use! Please choose another username');";
        echo "history.back();";
        echo "</script>";
      }
        
      
      else
      {
        
        mysqli_free_result($result);
      
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (account, password, name, sex, 
                year, month, day, telephone, address,
                email, comment) VALUES ('$account', '$password', 
                '$name', '$sex', $year, $month, $day, '$telephone', 
                '$address', '$email', '$comment')";
    
        $result = execute_sql($link, "member", $sql);
    
        echo "User added successfully!";
      }
        
      
      mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

**join.html**

```
<form action="addmember.php" method="POST" name="myForm">
(Different types of input)
<input type="submit" value="Add">
```

My aim is to add a member data into the database after the user clicked the `Add` button on the form in `join.html`. However the page could run `echo "User added successfully!";` this line but the problem is the database could not get updated even though I already called `execute_sql` command. May I ask what is missing in order to be connected with the database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text from PDF file with IDENTITY-H fonts using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331421/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-file-with-identity-h-fonts-using-vb-net)

Comment: Is your form getting submitted? Are you getting input into `$_POST`. Also try closing the form with `</form>` tag.

Comment: if `execute_sql` your own function ? If so, please check if it's working fine.

Comment: Although it submits the database record does not update accordingly

Comment: Can you once check what you are getting in `$_POST`

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the input values from ```join.html```

Comment: I could not figure out where is the problem in ```$_POST``` since I am retrieving according to the input name that I have set

Comment: Can someone tell me what is missing?